How to add properties to a manual trigger
How do i add properties to a message sent through "Manual" trigger?  just like when a message is sent through servicebus trigger.
I can add Body and Property parameter but the content of the Property parameter needs to be accessed just like it came from servicebus e.g trigger.data.Properties.CorrelationId.
But i get errors like "'string' does not contain a definition for 'CorrelationId'"
I have added the value of properties to the parameter like this:
{
        "messageType": "HelloworldmessageType",
        "CorrelationId": "0b504ce4-81c3-4fd3-bb87-5ed933146cb7",
        "BrokerProperties.CorrelationId": null,
        "BrokerProperties.SessionId": null,
        "BrokerProperties.DeliveryCount": 1,
        "BrokerProperties.LockedUntilUtc": "2024-12-19T08:36:13.578+00:00",
        "BrokerProperties.LockToken": "3888e999-8828-403a-8f77-be9b99290fa4",
        "BrokerProperties.MessageId": "ab6377e6ed7646c584a769ea23e56045",
        "BrokerProperties.Label": "HelloWorld",
        "BrokerProperties.ReplyTo": null,
        "BrokerProperties.EnqueuedTimeUtc": "2024-12-19T08:35:13.562+00:00",
        "BrokerProperties.TimeToLive": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
        "BrokerProperties.To": null,
        "BrokerProperties.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
        "BrokerProperties.ReplyToSessionId": null,
        "BrokerProperties.ContentType": null
    }

comparing the incoming data in the servicebus trigger and manual trigger it looks identical. Both have a Body part and a Properties part. The content of the Properties look correct with all the values, still i can't access them.
example of message through servicebus:
{
    "Body": "Hello World message",
    "Properties": {
        "messageType": "HelloworldmessageType",
        "CorrelationId": "0b504ce4-81c3-4fd3-bb87-5ed933146cb7",
        "BrokerProperties.CorrelationId": null,
        "BrokerProperties.SessionId": null,
        "BrokerProperties.DeliveryCount": 1,
        "BrokerProperties.LockedUntilUtc": "2024-12-19T08:36:13.578+00:00",
        "BrokerProperties.LockToken": "3888e999-8828-403a-8f77-be9b99290fa4",
        "BrokerProperties.MessageId": "ab6377e6ed7646c584a769ea23e56045",
        "BrokerProperties.Label": "HelloWorld",
        "BrokerProperties.ReplyTo": null,
        "BrokerProperties.EnqueuedTimeUtc": "2024-12-19T08:35:13.562+00:00",
        "BrokerProperties.TimeToLive": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
        "BrokerProperties.To": null,
        "BrokerProperties.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
        "BrokerProperties.ReplyToSessionId": null,
        "BrokerProperties.ContentType": null
    }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
